# Cascalog: start uberjar and main on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, clojure, uberjar, cascalog

I have compiled an uberjar from a file like:

```
(defmain HadoopTest (:use 'cascalog.api) (defn bla ("alot of code"))
```

I run that uberjar on hadoop like:

`$ hadoop jar myStandalone.jar clojure.main`

and i get a REPL, but nothing from that file is executed. I still have to type (:use 'cascalog.api) and (defn bla) by hand. Why is that the case and how do i fix it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply a class name to `hadoop jar <jar file> [<main class>] ...` it will call the `main` method that is contained in that class. Since you are using `clojure.main` here, a REPL will be spun up (because that's what `clojure.main.main()` is supposed to do).

So, either use the right class (your AOT-compiled Clojure namespace, I guess), or store that information in your Uberjar (e.g. via Leiningen's `:main` key in the project file) and leave out the classname, calling only `hadoop jar myStandalone.jar`.

Comment: Thank you very much, is it also possible to call main class and use REPL? or only REPL or Main class?

Comment: If you want a REPL with a number of namespaces already loaded, you could actually use the `--eval` parameter: `hadoop jar myStandalone.jar clojure.main --eval "(use 'my.namespace)" --repl` should evaluate `(use 'my.namespace)` before offering a REPL prompt. (Something like `--eval "(require 'my.namespace) (apply my.namespace/-main *command-line-args*)"` would probably work for directly calling a function, although it seems messy and I'd not really recommend it.)